# I want to know the second argument of application

Tags: javascript

```js
function printProfile(name, age, ...args) {
    return `${this.type} ${name} Age:${age}${args.length === 0 ? '' : ' ' + this.feature + ':' + args.join(',')}`
}
const developer = {
    type: 'Developer',
    feature: 'Language'
};
const artist = {
    type: 'Artist',
    feature: 'Song'
};
```

```js
printProfile.apply(developer, ? )  // --> 'Developer jack Age:30'
printProfile.apply(developer, ? )  // --> 'Developer jin Age:20 Language:JavaScript'
printProfile.apply(artist,  ?  )   // --> 'Artist BTS Age:7 Song:ON,Dynamite'
```

The second argument is `'?'`.  I wonder what it is.

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of the apply is an array of items that will match the position of your function arguments. And any left over goes to the args param. Here is one example, and from this you should be able to grasp the concept to figure out the rest.

```
       printProfile.apply(developer, ['Joe', 34, 'JavaScript'])
```

**Resources**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

**Test Snippet**

```js
function printProfile(name, age, ...args) {
    return `${this.type} ${name} Age:${age}${args.length === 0 ? '' : ' ' + this.feature + ':' + args.join(',')}`
}
const developer = {
    type: 'Developer',
    feature: 'Language'
};
const artist = {
    type: 'Artist',
    feature: 'Song'
};

const result = printProfile.apply(developer, ['Joe', 34, 'JavaScript'])

console.log(result)
```